# UIGestureRecognizer on UIView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to apply `UIGestureRecognizer` on UIView inside a `UITableViewCell`?

Or is there any way to detect that the `UIView` is tapped?

Comment: can you not meet your requirements with unbutton?

Comment: Isn't there any other way around other than placing a UIButton on UIView and write a selector ?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit what you are trying to achieve with UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I tried adding a tap gesture on the table view cell and seems to work perfectly. So yes, it is possible. Can you add an example code that produces this issue.

Comment: And for the rest of you: 1.: If you require a tap gesture you should not suggest a button. 2.: The table view cell has more "like a button system" rather then a tap gesture and again, no, we do NOT need to use buttons. Gestures do work and 3. if everything else fails you may simply set the gesture delegate including functionality to work simultaneously with other gestures.

Comment: I think swipe gesture is not possible to implement on table view. I tried to implement it ,but failed. @MaticOblak

Comment: I just had to try that and it just works @T_77

Comment: Yes,it is possible to add tap gesture,can you please add a piece of code where exactly you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, I was implementing Pinch Gesture to UIView to detect Tap rather using Tap Gesture.

I implemented Tap Gesture and it worked like a charm.